# How access to variables within an anonymous function?

Tags: javascript

I have an anonymous function inside a variable `GLOBAL`.

```
var GLOBAL = function (){

  var func1 = function(){

    console.log("function 1 go!")

  }

  var func2 = function(){

    console.log("function 2 go!")

  }

  return {

    init: function(){

        func1();

    }

  }

}()
```

In my init function return `func1`, calling it so `GLOBAL.init();`.

**My question is: how I can call functions directly for example `GLOBAL.func1()` or `GLOBAL.func2()`.**

Comment: You can't unless you pass the reference via the return

Comment: Why do you want to do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to return the function references,

```
var GLOBAL = function (){
  var func1 = function(){
    console.log("function 1 go!");
  }
  var func2 = function(){
    console.log("function 2 go!")
  }
  return { func1,func2 };
}();
```

Now you can access it like `GLOBAL.func1()` and  `GLOBAL.func2()`. And do not confuse with the syntax `{ func1,func2 };`. That is quite similar to `{ func1 : func1,func2 : func2 };` I just used the shorthand introduced in ES6.

Comment: What kinda pattern is this?

Comment: @Roy Singleton pattern.

Answer (score 2):

You can't. They are locally scoped variables. Being inaccessible outside the function is a large part of the point.

If you want them to be accessible, then you need to make them so explicitly (as you have done for the anonymous function you assign to `init`).

Answer (score 1):

You should explicit add those functions in the returned object. In this code you can still continue executing init() as a object initialization.

```js
var GLOBAL = function (){
  
  var func1 = function(){
    console.log("function 1 go!")
  };

  var func2 = function(){
    console.log("function 2 go!")
  }

  return {
    init: function(){
        this.func1();
    }, 
    func1, 
    func2
  }

}();

GLOBAL.func1();
GLOBAL.func2();
```

I hope that helps :D

Answer (score 0):

You can follow modular approach if it can help:

```
var GLOBAL = {
    func1: function(){
           console.log("function 1 go!")
    },
    func2: function(){
           console.log("function 2 go!")
    }
}

GLOBAL.func1();
GLOBAL.func2();
```